# General API Advice - Apollo or Relay Modern for GraphQL?

Tags: django, graphql, apollo, graphene-python, relaymodern

At a crossroads in my project where I need to decide which way to venture forward with my front end API.

I am using a Django-GraphQL back end and so far a React front end.

I chose React because I am new to this style of app development and React appears to be the simplest(read, easiest for a me to understand) to implement of the popular ones I can find.

I know would like to use either Apollo or Relay Modern to serve the GraphQl data to the front end app.

Relay Modern seems like it would make the most sense with it's fragmenting options and some built in features in graphene-django already supporting it.

With my limited time doing this as more of a hobby than anything, I need to invest my time spent learning wisely. Before I dive down the rabbit hole of either side, I'd like some advice/opinions from folks who have used either/or/both.

If this is the wrong forum to post this in my apologies.

Comment: This question isn't really appropriate for SO, but it **has** been asked and answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43306989/relay-vs-redux-vs-apollo-with-graphql-and-react-native) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43233760/what-are-the-differences-between-apollo-client-and-relay/43256057#43256057).

Comment: Thanks! I did see those but with the age of them I was concerned since things seem to change so fast with these libraries/frameworks. In the future, where would you recommend posting a question such as this?

Comment: You can google "Relay vs Apollo" and you'll find a number of articles that cover the differences in detail, as well as posts on the topic on other sites.

Comment: Daniel why link to ancient outdated answers that does not hold true anymore? Not really helping in 2019...